# How can get rid of this window?

Tags: debugging

Actually, I don't know what happened and the bellow window appeared in *Mathematica* v10 and I can't get rid of this, Although I went to **Evaluation** **Quit Kernel** **Local**, it temporarily disappears but again will be shown which drives me crazy!

[image]

Also, however I can't remember, but I think previously, on the top of the *Mathematica* window the word "Debug" had been not appeared however I continuously I see it.

[image]

Comment: You need to disable it in the Evaluation menu.  Uncheck Evaluation -> Debugger.

Comment: No, it is a bug in Mathematica. The Debugger option is already unchecked but this window still appear. The temporary workaround is for every window check and uncheck again the debugger option. However, it will appear again on next start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose Evaluation - Uncheck debugger

If it appears again even after you uncheck, save the program, close MMA and restart. It shouldn't reappear (at-least in my case, seems like its a bug).

[See this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/Debugger.html)